# Flutter Dart why changing the object type does not result in an error?

Tags: function, flutter, dart, types

I am new to dart.
I am working with Futures and learning more about types along the way (coming from a python background, so no experience in types). My code has no errors but, kindly explain to me why I can change my function's type from `Future<List>` when creating it to `Function` in `initState`. Here is the code:

```
Future<List> getData() async {
    String ss = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
      return 'first name';
    });
    String ssTwo = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
      return 'last name here.';
    });

    List lista = [ss, ssTwo];
    return lista;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Function getit = getData; // Why if I set it to Future<List> in here I get an exceptio? 
    print('placeholder');
    super.initState();
  }
```

Why in `initState` if I set the type to `Future<List>` I get this exception?

```
A value of type 'Future<List<dynamic>> Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<dynamic>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Future<List<dynamic>>'.
```

Comment: Assigning `getData` to a `Function` does not generate an error because it already *is* a `Function`.   That function *returns* a `Future<List>`, but you are not *calling* the function.

Answer (score 3):

The `getData()` return `Future<List>` while you tring to assign `Future<List>` in to a `Function()` that's why you are getting error

Try this way to get `Future<List>` from `getData()` method

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData().then((list) =>
    {
      list.forEach((element) {
        debugPrint('LIST_ITEM $element');
      })
    });
    print('placeholder');
  }
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: I know, I just want to know why I can't assign ```Future<List>``` type to ```getData``` inside ```initState```.
I'm not trying to find a solution, I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: You're assigning a function type of `Future<List<dynamic>> Function()` to `Future<List<dynamic>>`. See the difference? `getData` is a function reference while `getData()` is calling the function and assigning the returned value.